# How can I filter http requests by type in Safari 6 Developer Tools?

Tags: safari

In older versions of Safari and Chrome you can filter http requests to only show xhr requests for example. This seems to have been removed in the Safari 6 developer tools.

Am I missing something, an undocumented hot key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Instruments panel (the icon of the stopwatch), click Network Requests on the left. You should then see the timeline on the left, and a list of requests underneath. Click the Type column heading to sort the requests by type and then all the XHR requests will be grouped together.

Alternatively, in Safari's Develop menu, you can select "Use WebKit Web Inspector" to switch back to the old inspector.

[image: Develop Menu]

Comment: The alternative is what I'm looking for but I do not see an option to "Use WebKit Web Inspector". I've been using the sort on type as a replacement since the switch over but I do not like it.

Comment: @Mark: see screenshot above.

Comment: Odd, I definitely do not have that. What build of Safari 6 are you using? 8536.25 is mine on OS X 10.8.1

Comment: I'm running 7536.25 on 10.7.4. Maybe they took that option out when running under 10.8?

Comment: Noooo...that sucks. I was hoping it was just me. :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: To follow up on this, I've since upgraded my computer to Mountain Lion and I no longer have that menu option either. I'm guessing the old Web Inspector was specific to Lion.

Answer (score 0):

The Safari filtering of XHR in Safari 6 and 7 is different to any of the other browser tools that I know of.

You need to go to the Resources pane and in the navigation sidebar on the left you will see folders that group resources.
To get to *Resources* from the Safari menu, choose *Develop > Show Page Resources* or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or select the Resources icon from the toolbar when in Web Inspector.

If the page has any XHR responses you will see an *XHRs* folder there with the XHRs listed below it. Other resource folders include Stylesheets, Scripts, Images and so on.

You can navigate these 'folders' (they are logical, not real) via the navigation sidebar, or the navigation bar.

Selecting an XHR from either the navigation sidebar or navigation bar, shows the response in the main content browser, and other details in the details sidebar.

I'm using terms from the [Safari Web Inspector Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)